# DynamicObject databinding on DataGridView, System.Dynamic namespace

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview, dynamicobject

I have some collections of objects that inherits DynamicObject class, all works great with the BindingSource and BindingNavigator, but I don't have the dynamic properties displayed on the DatagridView.

The objects inherits DynamicObject and overrides the TrySetMember, TryGetMethod and GetDynamicMemberNames, I think that it is sufficient.

It also implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface for the binding updates.

I'm forgetting something? or is it possible to do?

what I have now is:

```
protected BindingList<Users> _Users;
_Users = _Ctl.GetAll();

BndSrc.DataSource = _Users;

BndNav.BindingSource = BndSrc;

Grid.DataSource = BndSrc;
```

Note: the _Ctl is a object that gives me all the users, the Users class inherits DynamicObject and have properties defined dynamically, like Username, Password and Name, it is all working well, but the datagrid don't display the dynamic properties.

Comment: Can you post an example?

Comment: I edited the question and included an example

Comment: Your post title and tags indicate this is a C# question - but your sample is in VB.NET?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I work a lot with the 2 languages, but the question is valid for both.

Comment: I'm confused - this is WinForms DataGridView, not WPF DataGrid? If so, why do you say you implemented INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: Is WinForms, the INotifyProperty is used to notify the binded controls that a property in a object has changed, and vice-versa.

Comment: You might check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473739/binding-dynamicobject-to-a-datagrid-with-automatic-column-generation/5299311#5299311  it's for a WPF datagrid but sometimes they work the same.

Answer (score 1):

Databinding to dynamic (DynamicObject) objects is broken and MS has resolved it as "Wont fix".

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/522119/databinding-to-dynamic-objects-is-broken