# WPF DataGrid AutoGenerateColumn base class inheritance

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, gridview

I have a problem showing items of a special type in a `DataGrid`. I created a minimal example.

Let´s say I have an abstract `BaseClass` and many inheriting `ChildClasses`:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public int BaseProperty { get; set; }
}

//Many ChildClasses possible
public class ChildClass : BaseClass
{
    public int ChildProperty { get; set; }
}
```

My DataContext contains a collection of all items:

```
public ObservableCollection<BaseClass> Items { get; set; }
```

Now I want to show all items of the collection of a special type in a GridView. To filter out a type, I created a `CollectionViewSource`:

```
<CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Items}" x:Key="ChildClasses" Filter="ChildClassesFilter"/>
```

And here is the resulting `GridView` using the `CollectionViewSource`:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ChildClasses}"/>
```

**Now my problem:**
In the `DataGrid` only the `BaseProperty` is shown (`AutoGenerateColumns`) automatically. How can I force WPF to show also the `ChildProperty` without describing the property in the XAML?

Or is there a different approach to show only the items of a special type in my `GridView`?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do can't work, because the properties shown in data grid columns have to be present in every entry of the `Items` collection. Only the properties declared in your `BaseClass` are guaranteed to be present in every instance that is put into the `Items` collection.

That is the reason why `AutoGenerateColumns` does not create columns of the child instances. You have several options how to fix that:

1. Change your collection to take only instances of your `ChildClass`
2. Implement your `ChildProperty` in your `BaseClass` and have the `ChildClass` overload it
3. Use a Wrapper Objekt that contains all properties you want to expose and have it handle fetching the correct values and properties based on the type of the wrapped object.
4. You could use dynamic objects and type descriptors to fetch the properties of every object. There is a example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473739/binding-dynamicobject-to-a-datagrid-with-automatic-column-generation) how that could work.
5. You declare the columns in XAML.