# C# DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns for dynamic Object inside Wrapper

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm trying to implement some kind of Object Picker in WPF. So far I've created the Window with a **DataGrid** which ItemsSource is bound to an **ObservableCollection**. I also set **AutoGenerateColumns** to 'true' due to the fact that the Item to be picked can be any kind ob object.
The Objects inside the Collection are wrapped in a **SelectionWrapper< T>** which contains an IsSelected Property in order to select them.

```
class SelectionWrapper<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // Following Properties including PropertyChanged
    public bool IsSelected { [...] }
    public T Model { [...] }
}
```

I also added a CustomColumn to the DataGrid.Columns in order to bind the IsSelected Property like so

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding SourceView}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Selected" Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The result I get with this solution is not very satisfying because there is just my defined Column 'Selected' and two GeneratedColumns 'IsSelected' and 'Model'.

Is there a way to change the target for the AutoGeneration to display all Properties of Model instead?
Also it is necessary to make the AutoGeneratedColumns ReadOnly because no one should edit the displayed Entries.

It is no option to turn off AutoGenerateColumns and add some more manual Columns like

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Model.[SomeProperty]}"/>
```

because the Model can be of any kind of Object. Maybe there is a way to route the target for AutoGeneration to the Model Property?

Thanks in Advance

## Edit

After accepting the Answer of @grek40
I came up with the following

First I created a general class of SelectionProperty which is inherited in `SelectionProperty<T>`. Here I implement the Interface `ICustomTypeDescriptor` which finally looked like:

```
public abstract class SelectionProperty : NotificationalViewModel, ICustomTypeDescriptor
{
    bool isSelected = false;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return this.isSelected; }
        set
        {
            if (this.isSelected != value)
            {
                this.isSelected = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
            }
        }
    }

    object model = null;
    public object Model
    {
        get { return this.model; }
        set
        {
            if (this.model != value)
            {
                this.model = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("Model");
            }
        }
    }

    public SelectionProperty(object model)
    {
        this.Model = model;
    }
#region ICustomTypeDescriptor
[...]
    PropertyDescriptorCollection ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetProperties()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this.Model.GetType());
    }

    object ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetPropertyOwner(PropertyDescriptor pd)
    {
        if (pd.DisplayName == "IsSelected")
            return this;

        return this.Model;
    }
#endregion
```

Then I created a specialized ObservableCollection

```
class SelectionPropertyCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>, ITypedList
    where T : SelectionProperty
{
    public SelectionPropertyCollection(IEnumerable<T> collection) : base(collection)
    {

    }

    public PropertyDescriptorCollection GetItemProperties(PropertyDescriptor[] listAccessors)
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T).GenericTypeArguments[0]);
    }

    public string GetListName(PropertyDescriptor[] listAccessors)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Well and the last thing is the ViewModel. The most significant lines are

```
class ObjectPickerViewModel<ObjectType> : BaseViewModel
{
    public ICollectionView SourceView { get; set; }
    SelectionPropertyCollection<SelectionProperty<ObjectType>> source = null;
    public SelectionPropertyCollection<SelectionProperty<ObjectType>> Source
    {
        get { return this.source; }
        set
        {
            if (this.source != value)
            {
                this.source = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("Source");
            }
        }
    }
    // [...]
    this.Source = new SelectionPropertyCollection<SelectionProperty<ObjectType>>(source.Select(x => new SelectionProperty<ObjectType>(x)));
    this.SourceView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.Source);
}
```

The good thing here is, that I can still add more Columns in the XAML but also have all public Properties of the Wrapped Object!

Comment: See [Binding DynamicObject to a DataGrid with automatic column generation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5299311/5265292) for a possible way... gonna write an answer, but it's neither going to be trivial nor complete ;)

Comment: I think this goes in the wrong way (maybe). The thing is, that the Property 'Model' inside the SelectionWrapper can be of any type i.e. Tuple, DateTime, and so on. If I leave the Wrapper and bind directly to a Collection of T all Properties are build automatically as expected but then im missing the 'IsSelected' Column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the course of [Binding DynamicObject to a DataGrid with automatic column generation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2473739/5265292), the following should work to some extent but I'm not quite sure if I would ever use something like it in production:

Create a collection that implements `ITypedList` and `IList`. `GetItemProperties` from `ITypedList` will be used. Expect the list type to implement `ICustomTypeDescriptor`:

```
public class TypedList<T> : List<T>, ITypedList, IList
    where T : ICustomTypeDescriptor
{
    public PropertyDescriptorCollection GetItemProperties(PropertyDescriptor[] listAccessors)
    {
        if (this.Any())
        {
            return this[0].GetProperties();
        }
        return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(new PropertyDescriptor[0]);
    }

    public string GetListName(PropertyDescriptor[] listAccessors)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Implement `SelectionWrapper<T>` as `DynamicObject` and implement `ICustomTypeDescriptor` (at least the `PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties()` method)

```
public class SelectionWrapper<T> : DynamicObject, INotifyPropertyChanged, ICustomTypeDescriptor
{
    private bool _IsSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _IsSelected; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _IsSelected, value); }
    }


    private T _Model;
    public T Model
    {
        get { return _Model; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _Model, value); }
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        if (Model != null)
        {
            var prop = typeof(T).GetProperty(binder.Name);
            // indexer member will need parameters... not bothering with it
            if (prop != null && prop.CanRead && prop.GetMethod != null && prop.GetMethod.GetParameters().Length == 0)
            {
                result = prop.GetValue(Model);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return base.TryGetMember(binder, out result);
    }

    public override IEnumerable<string> GetDynamicMemberNames()
    {
        // not returning the Model property here
        return typeof(T).GetProperties().Select(x => x.Name).Concat(new[] { "IsSelected" });
    }

    public PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties()
    {
        var props = GetDynamicMemberNames();
        return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(props.Select(x => new DynamicPropertyDescriptor(x, GetType(), typeof(T))).ToArray());
    }

    // some INotifyPropertyChanged implementation

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void RaisePropertyChangedEvent([CallerMemberName]string prop = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }

    protected bool SetProperty<T2>(ref T2 store, T2 value, [CallerMemberName]string prop = null)
    {
        if (!object.Equals(store, value))
        {
            store = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent(prop);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    // ... A long list of interface method implementations that just throw NotImplementedException for the example
}
```

The `DynamicPropertyDescriptor` hacks a way to access the properties of the wrapper and the wrapped object.

```
public class DynamicPropertyDescriptor : PropertyDescriptor
{
    private Type ObjectType;
    private PropertyInfo Property;
    public DynamicPropertyDescriptor(string name, params Type[] objectType) : base(name, null)
    {
        ObjectType = objectType[0];
        foreach (var t in objectType)
        {
            Property = t.GetProperty(name);
            if (Property != null)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public override object GetValue(object component)
    {
        var prop = component.GetType().GetProperty(Name);
        if (prop != null)
        {
            return prop.GetValue(component);
        }
        DynamicObject obj = component as DynamicObject;
        if (obj != null)
        {
            var binder = new MyGetMemberBinder(Name);
            object value;
            obj.TryGetMember(binder, out value);
            return value;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public override void SetValue(object component, object value)
    {
        var prop = component.GetType().GetProperty(Name);
        if (prop != null)
        {
            prop.SetValue(component, value);
        }
        DynamicObject obj = component as DynamicObject;
        if (obj != null)
        {
            var binder = new MySetMemberBinder(Name);
            obj.TrySetMember(binder, value);
        }
    }

    public override Type PropertyType
    {
        get { return Property.PropertyType; }
    }

    public override bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return !Property.CanWrite; }
    }

    public override bool CanResetValue(object component)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public override Type ComponentType
    {
        get { return typeof(object); }
    }

    public override void ResetValue(object component)
    {
    }

    public override bool ShouldSerializeValue(object component)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public class MyGetMemberBinder : GetMemberBinder
{
    public MyGetMemberBinder(string name)
        : base(name, false)
    {

    }
    public override DynamicMetaObject FallbackGetMember(DynamicMetaObject target, DynamicMetaObject errorSuggestion)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
public class MySetMemberBinder : SetMemberBinder
{
    public MySetMemberBinder(string name)
        : base(name, false)
    {

    }
    public override DynamicMetaObject FallbackSetMember(DynamicMetaObject target, DynamicMetaObject value, DynamicMetaObject errorSuggestion)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Now if you bind some `TypedList<SelectionWrapper<ItemViewModel>>` to your datagrid itemssource, it should populate the columns for `IsSelected` and for the properties of `ItemViewModel`.

Let me say it again - the whole approach is a bit hacky and my implementation here is far from being stable.

As I think about it some more, there is probably no real need for the whole `DynamicObject` stuff as long as the `TypedList` is used to define the columns and some `DynamicPropertyDescriptor` to access the properties from wrapper and model.

Comment: I accepted your answer even so I broke it down to a minimum and adjusted it for my needs. I will edit my post. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Fresch Well, it was fun to try making it work and it was a new topic for me too, so I didn't create *the best* solution, just something that shows it can be done :)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to change the target for the AutoGeneration to display all Properties of Model instead?

Short answer: No.

Only a column per public property of the type `T` of the `IEnumerable<T>` that you set as the `ItemsSource` will be created.

You should consider setting the `AutoGenerateColumns` property to `false` and creating the columns programmatically instead of hard-coding them in your XAML markup.

Comment: That may break the MVVM pattern doesnt it (Guess I forgot to mention that I use that pattern)? But maybe i'm wrong. Some implementation ideas/code?

Comment: No, why would it? You are creating the columns in the same view class, aren't you? MVVM is not about eliminating code from the views. In fact, you can define an entire view programmaticaly without using XAML and without breaking the MVVM pattern.