# Dynamical / expanding entries for Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I'm trying to create a datagrid which has a entries which have properties coming from a json. The problem is that a lot of the properties should be dynamically generated based on the information that is in the json.

The first thing I tried was to make a very long list of all possible properties with their own getters & seters. But it's a very long list and it felt like there should be an automated solution for this problem. This is included at the end of Datagrid Entry View Model. So I am able to bind to Number when:

```
Number = obj.NUMBER;
```

After that I researched into dynamic types and expandoObjects. I learned that apperently it's not possible to bind WPF to an expandoObject's expanded properties. So I cannot bind to expando.Number

```
expando.Number = obj.NUMBER
```

I also tried to follow [this](http://julmar.com/blog/programming/dynamic-type-binding-in-wpf-4-5/) example in which helper classes are created to help with the binding, but I can't seem to get it to work. When I run my solution I get an error saying that the property "Numberz" doesn't exist. So I cannot bind to Numberz:

```
AddProperty("Numberz", typeof(string));
SetPropertyValue("Numberz", obj.NUMBER);
```

At moment I'm out of ideas, so if anybody here could help, I would be very grateful. Maybe a few last notes. I'm not a very experienced programmer and I'm trying to work through an MVVM-pattern.

**Datagrid entry view model**

public class DatagridEntryViewModel : ICustomTypeProvider, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region Fields

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Custom Type provider implementation - delegated through static methods.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly CustomTypeHelper<DatagridEntryViewModel> _helper = new CustomTypeHelper<DatagridEntryViewModel>();

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    public DatagridEntryViewModel(ExitCoil model) 
    {
        _helper.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => PropertyChanged(this, e);

        dynamic Json = JObject.Parse(model.JsonCoilData);
        //CreationDatePost = Json.CREATION_DATE_S_POST;
        ////Number = Json.NUMBER;
        //CreationDatePost = Json.CREATION_DATE_S_POST;
        ////LeverageOrder = Json.LEVERAGE_ORDER;
        //Client = Json.CLIENT;
        //Skinned = Json.SKINNED;

        dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();
        dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(Json.ToString());
        //AddProperty("Numberz", typeof(string));
        //SetPropertyValue("Numberz", obj.NUMBER);
        //expando.AddItem("Number");
        //expando[0] = obj.NUMBER;
        //Number = expando.Number;


        Model = model;

        //var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        //settings.Converters.Add(new Models.DynamicJsonConverter());
        //var serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(settings);
        //JsonReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(JsonString));

        //var Data = serializer.Deserialize<DynamicObject>(reader);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Model & proxy

    private ExitCoil _model;
    public ExitCoil Model
    {
        set { _model = value; }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Public Methods

    // Methods to support dynamic properties.
    public static void AddProperty(string name)
    {
        CustomTypeHelper<DatagridEntryViewModel>.AddProperty(name);
    }

    public static void AddProperty(string name, Type propertyType)
    {
        CustomTypeHelper<DatagridEntryViewModel>.AddProperty(name, propertyType);
    }

    public static void AddProperty(string name, Type propertyType, List<Attribute> attributes)
    {
        CustomTypeHelper<DatagridEntryViewModel>.AddProperty(name, propertyType, attributes);
    }

    public void SetPropertyValue(string propertyName, object value)
    {
        _helper.SetPropertyValue(propertyName, value);
    }

    public object GetPropertyValue(string propertyName)
    {
        return _helper.GetPropertyValue(propertyName);
    }

    public PropertyInfo[] GetProperties()
    {
        return _helper.GetProperties();
    }

    Type ICustomTypeProvider.GetCustomType()
    {
        return _helper.GetCustomType();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
    private void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    //public string Number { get; private set; }

    //public string CreationDatePost { get; private set; }

    //public string LeverageOrder { get; private set; }

    public string Client { get; private set; }

    //public int OrderZnTop { get; private set; }

    //public int OrderZnBottom { get; private set; }

    //public string OrderAspect { get; private set; }

    //public string OderSideTrimming { get; private set; }

    //public string OrderPassivation { get; private set; }

    //public string OrderOilType { get; private set; }

    //public string OrderOilQuantity { get; private set; }


    #endregion

}
```

**Datagrid view model**

```
public class DatagridViewModel : MainViewModelBase
    {
        #region Singleton

        public static DatagridViewModel Instance = new DatagridViewModel();

        #endregion

        #region Fields

        private ObservableCollection<DatagridEntryViewModel> _coilEntries = new ObservableCollection<DatagridEntryViewModel>();
        private readonly IViewManager _viewManager;
        private readonly IDockManager _dockManager;

        #endregion

        #region Properties

        public ObservableCollection<DatagridEntryViewModel> CoilEntries
        {
            get { return _coilEntries; }
            set
            {
                _coilEntries = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => CoilEntries);
            }
        }

        public ProductionExitCoilReport Report { get; set; }

        #endregion

        #region Constructor

        public DatagridViewModel()
        {
            _viewManager = Globals.Container.Resolve<IViewManager>();
            _dockManager = Globals.Container.Resolve<IDockManager>();


            getReport();

            foreach (var Coil in Report.Coils)
            {
                CoilEntries.Add(new DatagridEntryViewModel(Coil));
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Methods

        public void getReport()
        {
            var proxy = new Proxy<IReportService>();
            proxy.Open();
            var LijnId = new LijnIdentificatie { Department = "HDG", Firm = "LIE", LineNumber = "05" };
            var Periode = new Period { FromDate = new DateTime(2017 - 11 - 10), FromShift = 1, ToDate = new DateTime(2017 - 11 - 10), ToShift = 1 };
            var request = new ProductionReportRequest() { LijnIdentificatie = LijnId, Period = Periode };
            Report = proxy.Service.GetProductionExitCoilReport(request);


        }

        #endregion
    }
```

**Datagrid XAML**

```
<DataGrid x:Class="Promo.Presentation.Views.CoilGrid"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/marukp-compatibility/2006" 
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Promo.Presentation.Views"
            xmlns:components="clr-namespace:Promo.Presentation.Components"
            xmlns:Data="clr-namespace:Promo.Presentation.ViewModels"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            GridLinesVisibility="none"
            Background="White"
            Height="Auto"
            Width="Auto"
            MinWidth="500"
            MinHeight="500"
            DataContext="{x:Static Data:DatagridViewModel.Instance}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding CoilEntries}"
            IsReadOnly="True"
            HeadersVisibility="Column"
            Padding="10"
          >

    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="../Styles/Colors.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="../Styles/Datagrid.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </DataGrid.Resources>

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Numberz}" Header="Rolnummer" MaxWidth="125"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CreationDatePost}" Header="Post" MaxWidth="200"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding LeverageOrder}" Header="Leverage order" MaxWidth="200"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Client}" Header="Client" MaxWidth="400"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding OrderZnTop}" Header="Order zinc top" MaxWidth="200"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding OrderZnBottom}" Header="Order zinc bottom" MaxWidth="200"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding OrderAspect}" Header="Order aspect" MaxWidth="125"/>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding OrderSideTrimming, Converter={local:StringToBoolConverter}}" Header="Order Side Trimming" MaxWidth="200"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding OrderPassivation}" Header="Order Passivation" MaxWidth="200"/>

        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding Skinned, Converter={local:StringToBoolConverter}}" Header="Skinned" MaxWidth="200"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>

</DataGrid>
```

**Part of the Json**

{"NUMBER":"G571015110          ","CREATION_DATE_S_POST":"2017-05-11T00:00:00""LEVERAGE_ORDER":"FD72BIGA5W/8","CLIENT":"ARCELORMITTAL BELGIUM SA          "}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to build A WPF Datagrid with an unknown number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44202718/how-to-build-a-wpf-datagrid-with-an-unknown-number-of-columns)

Comment: Please do read through the whole problem @ASh. Mine is that my rows have dynamical properties, not the columns of the table itself.

Comment: I did read the whole problem, but some important bits of information are missing. Example of json structure will be helpful. DataGrid generates a columns for each entry property, so dynamic properties means dynamic columns to me

Comment: Then say it like that instead of just saying that it's duplicate. Anyhow, I've added extra information now.

Comment: Do you need all of those properties to be displayed? Could you not rely on a set of properties and then display more info? That is, if it is possible for you. What you are describing here is a scenario where there could be multitude of columns for each object, so I would limit what you can display and focus on a set of properties that would allow me to display concise data.

Comment: @XAMlMAX I see where you are going, but I don't see how that would solve the problem at this moment. I still would need to bind to a dynamic object or expandoObject of some kind? The difficulty for me is to convert the json to a list of properties which are bindable in WPF. Showing or hiding columns is a problem for later. But for example let's just say I want only to display the property "Number" without hardcoding (I've got more than 200 properties which I have to display somewhere).

Comment: If you have a json with all of the properties then Visual Studio can generate class for you! no need to create them your self. I worked on a similar scenario in the past, this has been done before :-). Look into generating classes in Visual Studio based on json. This should make it a bit easier for you.

Comment: @XAMlMAX That is very interesting, thanks. That made me cry a little (for all the unnecessary work I did). But we're moving to the right direction. The only thing I'm not sure of, is that I will ever have a json that contains all properties. Else it would be necessary to do that copy programmatically.

Comment: I don't understand every detail of your problem, but there might be a solution with `ICustomTypeDescriptor` and `ITypedList`... just remembered a related topic I worked on some time ago: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46950202/5265292 however, you should read on your own whether the presented concepts might be useful for your case, its not really straight forward :). Some more original topic: [Binding DynamicObject to a DataGrid with automatic column generation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2473739/5265292)

Comment: @XAMlMAX You can post your comment as answer. It's not a complete solution but it comes the closest and it was very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `json` with all of the properties then Visual Studio can generate class for you! no need to create them your self. I worked on a similar scenario in the past, this has been done before.
To paste a class generated from `json` click in your .cs file where you want to generate the code, then click on `Edit` in the Visual Studio menu, next select `Paste Special` and then select `Paste JSON As Classes`.
This should make it a bit easier for you.